# Exchange 2007 New SSL Certificate Breaks Iphone access

Tags: ssl, exchange-2007, https, iphone, rpc

I recently had to acquire a new CA cert for my Exchange 2007 server for OWA and Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTPS).  Since then,  all Iphone access to Exchange accounts has broken.  I have tried deleting the email account on the iphone, rebooting and reconfiguring accounts (thinking it needed to clear some cache related to the certificate).  On entering the new account, Iget"Exchange account verification failed"

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem,  MSExchangeSyncAppPool was not  started.

Answer (score 0):

Is your new certificate by any chance a wildcard cert? I.E. *.domain.com ? I don't believe the iPhone supports them.

Comment: no,  it is a fqdn subdomain cert...but it is configured exactly the same as the cert that was running successfully for over a year.  I think I may have gotten a bit farther in testing.  Around the same time I updated the cert,  I discovered a corruption in RPC over HTTP proxy so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it.  I got all of my Outlook 2007 clients using RPC over HTTPs running so I thought it was all good.  Now I am trying to go through these settings in the RPC folder,  but I can't seem to find any good docs on Exchange 2007 and iis7 (NOT iis6).